# Referencing images in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a script in a page (below) that calls a *jQuery* plugin and passes in the path to a number of images. The images are stored in *app/assets/img/bg* as opposed to *app/assets/images*.

```
<script>
    $(".forms-wrapper").backstretch([
        "assets/img/bg/6.jpg",
        "assets/img/bg/5.jpg",
        "assets/img/bg/7.jpg",
        ], {
            fade: 1000,
            duration: 7000
        });
</script>
```

The *JavaScript* function is in a file located in *app/assets/plugins/backstretch*.

I can get the functionality working by changing the path to the images and moving the images:-

```
<script>
    $(".forms-wrapper").backstretch([
        "../assets/7.jpg",
        "../assets/16.jpg",
        "../assets/19.jpg",
        ], {
            fade: 1000,
            duration: 7000
        });
</script>
```

I would rather not move the images as they are referenced from lots of different places. I have tried changing the path in the script to *./assets/img/bg/7.jpg* and this doesn’t work.

I seem to be having all sorts of problems with relative paths in rails because it seems to apply it’s own rules.

As another example there is a script that changes theme colors and images but this script is referencing the *img* folder too. I would need to reference the images folder here with a relative path (`../assets/img`) but relative paths don't appear to behave themselves properly.

```
var setColor = function (color, data_header) {
    jQuery('#style_color').attr("href", "assets/css/theme-colors/" + color + ".css");
    if(data_header == 'light'){
        jQuery('.logo img').attr("src", "assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
        jQuery('#logo-footer').attr("src", "assets/img/themes/logo2-" + color + ".png");
        jQuery('.navbar-brand img').attr("src", "assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
    } else if(data_header == 'dark'){
        jQuery('.logo img').attr("src", "assets/img/themes/logo1-" + color + ".png");
        jQuery('#logo-footer').attr("src", "assets/img/themes/logo2-" + color + ".png");
    }
}
```

How can I reliably address a subdirectory of assets to reference images? This issue manifests itself in different ways in different parts of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the assets helpers in Rails

```
$(".forms-wrapper").backstretch([
    "<%= image_path('bg/6.jpg') %>",
    "<%= image_path('bg/7.jpg') %>",
    "<%= image_path('bg/8.jpg') %>",
    ], {
        fade: 1000,
        duration: 7000
    });
```

This assumes the images are in `app/assets/images/img/bg` folder.

In general you send in the path following `app/assets/images`, meaning

```
image_path('logo.png')  # references app/assets/images/logo.png
```

---

**Edit:**

If you need to reference an unorthodox folder you can add this to your `config/initializers/assets.rb` (and restart)

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('assets', 'img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<script>
  $(".forms-wrapper").backstretch([
    "../assets/img/bg/6.jpg",
    "../assets/img/bg/5.jpg",
    "../assets/img/bg/7.jpg",
    ], {
      fade: 1000,
      duration: 7000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried this but this doesn't work either. The path it shows in the console is http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/img/bg/6.jpg but the image doesn't appear.

Comment: I think I am getting the path correct but rails is throwing a route error (No route matches [GET] "/assets/img/themes/logo2-orange.png). Referencing files and folders in rails seems like a b;lack art!

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me when I add it like this

```
$('.view').click(function (event){
    $(this).css("background", "url(/assets/sample.png) no-repeat");
    });
```